# ACE editor.getTextRange() what should the range be?

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

We have been trying to build an online IDE for PML. 
The editor is up but now we need to send the code from the editor to the server when the check button is pressed so that it can do PLM check there and send it back. The code from the editor is put as a string, but how should I send it to the server, all the answers fro the Internet seem to be concerned with AJAX, but I'm not sending an XML but a  string.
Anyone has any idea how to do it? 
Below is the function that is called when the button is clicked, data is the data from the editor. We are using ACE, now it's just alerting the code on the editor:

```
function sendData(){
      data = (editor.getSession().getValue());
      alert(data);
      //getValue() returns all the lines i
      // the document as a single string, split by the new line character.
    }
```

Comment: You can send a string via AJAX too, not just XML. Search on here there is quite a few post about it.

Comment: Thanks! I sorted it out